# How to read different data types from Firestore in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document saved in Firestore which looks similar to below:

```yaml
ArtistsUID: 7aPKTNRh5vdbFiEBKIPjhpCBDno1
DisplayName: iservetheface
LookName: HuhhInv
MediaURL: >-
    https:/firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/beautyboard-
    fcf88.appspot.com/o/looks_media%2FHuhh%20In%20v_7aPKT_24:
    alt=media&token=e846db3a-bb52-4925-9526-43334bbe9145
ProductsUsed:
    Contour:
        - Contour
        - hbbgch
        - bbbb
    Dry Shampoo:
        - Dry Shampoo
        - bcnbbg
        - cbbb
    Lashes:
        - Lashes
        - tatti
        - ngnnn
    TimeStamp: 'November 24,2020 at 11:44:18 PM UTC'
```

However I am not sure how to read this into my code in swift. I have a struct already defined as

```
struct LooksToAppend{
    let uid: String
    let DisplayName: String
    let LookName: String
    let MediaURL: String
    let TimeStamp: Date
    let ProductsUsed: [String:[String]]
    
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = dictionary["ArtistsUID"] as?String ?? ""
        self.DisplayName = dictionary["DisplayName"] as?String ?? ""
        self.LookName = dictionary["LookName"] as?String ?? ""
        self.MediaURL = dictionary["MediaURL"] as?String ?? ""
        self.TimeStamp = dictionary["TimeStamp"] as?Date ?? Date()
        self.ProductsUsed = dictionary["ProductsUsed"] as?Dictionary<String, Array<String>> ?? ["":["","",""]]
    }
}
```

Since ProductsUsed in Firestore is saved as a map data type and Timestamp is a timestamp I'm not sure how to read them back as when returned they are empty in my program.

I use the following code to get the data:

```
func LoadData() {
    db.collection("looks").getDocuments(){
        QuerySnapshot, error in
        if let error = error{
            print("Error loading")
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        else{
            self.LooksArray = QuerySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({LooksToAppend(dictionary: $0.data())})
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.LooksArray.shuffle()
                self.LooksTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map fields are basically `key-value` pairs that represent an object embedded within your Firebase document.

```
{a: "dfga", b: "bsaz"}
{b: "aaad", c: "badz"}
{c: "aaad"}
```

What does the output of your `ProductsUsed` look like? From my understanding, the `compactMap()` method works by applying some filtering to the output and any "nil" values are discarded. This might explain why your output is returned empty. You might be better to use `map()` instead.

```
let products = {
    "product1": [1, 2, 3],
    "product2": [1, 2, 4]
};

let mapped = products.map { $0.value }
// [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4]] : An array of arrays

print(mapped)
```